# Reverting file association with .dat file to blank

Tags: windows-10

My operating system is Windows 10. If more information is necessary, please ask.

I did a fair amount of research both with Google and even more dismayingly with the search underneath the title bar for this question. Unfortunately, one "solution" crushed my hopes when one possibility (software) gave me a prompt that it only runs on Windows 7 and Vista. I tried compatibility mode and it still didn't run!

I wanted to read a `.dat` file and accidentally set the file association with sublime text!

When attempting to revert to defaults within Settings it only reset the default apps for the Internet, video and other stuff.

There's no "x" for the option further down in the "choose default apps by file type" menu. I can't remove it within Windows. I'm still hunting, but I'm worried that an update or use of a `.dat` file might blue screen me due to my mistake.

The more hunting I did, the more I realized that not fixing this could brick my machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the file association, you can use the `assoc` command:

```
assoc .dat=
```

Reference: [assoc](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, as I'd mentioned the Reset to microsoft defaults doesn't reach all file associations. It only affected the immediate ones on that page. When I look into the choose default apps by file type, .dat is still associated with Sublime Text. There is no way to reach it within the settings menu. I used the reset button before I came here. Falling into despair atm.. I have nearly 1tb of data I'll need to redownload and configure if I need to reset... holy shit.. if I can... if I restart and the process to reset calls on .dat files I might not be able to.. definitely panicking now.

Comment: yeah I removed the `Reset` part before you commented; try the `assoc` command - it's the quickest way

Comment: I really screwed up royally though haven't I.. if I can't fix this and had previously attempted to reset my OS... I might not be here asking for help right now; Because it either would have fixed this or bricked my machine.

Comment: no - you’re fine. calm down, open command prompt, copy that small line of code into it, and press enter; it’s not a big deal

Comment: The icon for Sublime Text is still superimposed over the .dat file I tried to read. This isn't working...

Comment: if you don’t tamper with any of the files it won’t actually matter, as your system can still use/read the files as needed regardless of what program you open them with; if you’re worried about sublime specifically, just change it to Notepad and be done with it

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One is definitely to right click on the file in Windows Explorer, and click on "Open With". Then, from there, you can specify a different program to open .dat files and then click on "Always use selected to open .dat files".

A second way would be to go to the .dat file's properties and changing it there, which does the same thing in a different way. And the registry editor also offers this in ways I am not too familiar with; but the first and second ways are most likely foolproof.

Comment: Based on what I'd read, you don't want ANYTHING associated with .dat files b/c it can mess with how other programs try to call on them. Such as say... the  protected operating system .dat files themselves. This edit affects all the .dat files present on my PC. Talk about looking before you leap though.. this is my fault. I hope I can use the info here to fix it.

Comment: Well, operating system .dat files are not actually meant to open in any sort of graphical interface. After all, they are for the OS config and don't really affect anything for the average end user, so personally I don't think it would hurt to set a graphical interface to open all .dat files in. But the Registry Editor can also filter certain .dat files in locations if you create the necessary keys; however, that seems a little overkill for just setting how to open files.

Answer (score 0):

With the Registry Editor, locate the following:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dat
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dat_auto_file
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.dat
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\dat_auto_file
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ApplicationAssociationToasts\Applications\<the value for your dat file>
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.dat
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1362652250-3868838377-1918771581-1003\Software\Classes\.dat
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1362652250-3868838377-1918771581-1003\Software\Classes\dat_auto_file
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1362652250-3868838377-1918771581-1003\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ApplicationAssociationToasts\Applications\<the value for your dat file>
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1362652250-3868838377-1918771581-1003\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.dat
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1362652250-3868838377-1918771581-1003_Classes\.dat
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1362652250-3868838377-1918771581-1003_Classes\dat_auto_file
```

and delete them. Note that the ApplicationAssociationToasts keys must not be deleted, but the values referring to the DAT files inside them, instead. Make a backup before you edit the registry.

Answer (score -1):

Open a PowerShell window, then copy & paste the following comand:

```
Remove-item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.dat'
```

Log off & log back on.

Comment: That's like denying the problem exists and removing a file extension that's widely used.  The issue is some vendors (Dell!) hijack it to open their proprietary crapware.

Comment: That may be your issue, but it wasn't the OP'S. He asked for: ***Reverting file association with .dat file to blank***. And did not claim the extension was hijacked, but rather: ***... and accidentally set the file association with sublime text!***.